# Is it possible to wait on both channels and file descriptors at the same time in Go?

Tags: go, channel

I know I can wait on multiple channels using the `select {}` syntax in Go, and wait on multiple file descriptors using `syscall.Select()` or similar functions.  But is it possible to wait on both channels at once?

For background, I want to have a goroutine that accepts for messages over a channel and forwards them over a socket connection (provided by [gozmq](http://github.com/alecthomas/gozmq)), while simultaneously waiting for replies on the socket connection.

Due to the thread safety requirements of the underlying library, the socket can only be accessed in one thread at a time, which is why I was wondering if there is a way to handle this from a single goroutine.

Comment: Just for curiosity, that is the kind of thing you can do in other projects such as https://github.com/duckie/boson

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Selecting on both a channel and an file descriptor is not possible because the abstractions are at different levels. Channels are handled by the go runtime and file descriptors by the operating system. What you need is to make a bridge between them and this can be done with a `net.Pipe()`.

Pretty much what you need to do is dedicate one goroutine to `epoll()`/`select()` to watch your zmq-sockets and a single "wake up" `net.Pipe()`. This is your poll server. Another goroutine listens on your read and write channels. When someone sends on the read or write channels, the second goroutine would send on the pipe to wake up the poll server.

This is how the net package in the standard library works. I highly recommend reading it for inspiration (or stealing... the BSD license is very liberal).

Here is a description of pollServer from net itself. You may need to read the code to understand what this is saying, but this section from `fd.go` should be a good place to start looking.

```
// A pollServer helps FDs determine when to retry a non-blocking
// read or write after they get EAGAIN.  When an FD needs to wait,
// send the fd on s.cr (for a read) or s.cw (for a write) to pass the
// request to the poll server.  Then receive on fd.cr/fd.cw.
// When the pollServer finds that i/o on FD should be possible
// again, it will send fd on fd.cr/fd.cw to wake any waiting processes.
// This protocol is implemented as s.WaitRead() and s.WaitWrite().
//
// There is one subtlety: when sending on s.cr/s.cw, the
// poll server is probably in a system call, waiting for an fd
// to become ready.  It's not looking at the request channels.
// To resolve this, the poll server waits not just on the FDs it has
// been given but also its own pipe.  After sending on the
// buffered channel s.cr/s.cw, WaitRead/WaitWrite writes a
// byte to the pipe, causing the pollServer's poll system call to
// return.  In response to the pipe being readable, the pollServer
// re-polls its request channels.
//
// Note that the ordering is "send request" and then "wake up server".
// If the operations were reversed, there would be a race: the poll
// server might wake up and look at the request channel, see that it
// was empty, and go back to sleep, all before the requester managed
// to send the request.  Because the send must complete before the wakeup,
// the request channel must be buffered.  A buffer of size 1 is sufficient
// for any request load.  If many processes are trying to submit requests,
// one will succeed, the pollServer will read the request, and then the
// channel will be empty for the next process's request.  A larger buffer
// might help batch requests.
//
// To avoid races in closing, all fd operations are locked and
// refcounted. when netFD.Close() is called, it calls syscall.Shutdown
// and sets a closing flag. Only when the last reference is removed
// will the fd be closed.
```

Good luck re-implementing net. The good news at the end of all this your zmq-socket will be thread safe in go.

Comment: That sounds like it'd work: doing `select` or `poll` in another thread sounds unlikely to cause havoc with the thread safety requirements of zmq, so doing that in a goroutine and communicating the result back via a channel sounds like a good solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Spawn a new goroutine for each `fd` you wish to wait on, have them send the `fd` to a channel when they read something, select on the channels.

Comment: How do you tell these goroutine to stop ? Closing the fd is not a reliable way.

Comment: @chmike if closing a filedescriptor doesn't cause your thread to be notified - file a bug to your OS team. IOW, closing an FD is a documented, reliable way to have the process reading it notified.

Comment: The thread/process is notified if blocked in the read. Otherwise it is not. If an fd is closed, the kernel is free to reuse it. If this happens, the goroutine will not be aware of the closing and may start to read from another source identified with the reused fd. For this reason the only reliable solution is to use select on the fd and a pipe used to send a notification byte.

Comment: @chmike of course. Hence my idea is to create a goroutine that would read on the fd. When the fd is closed - it would stop, when the fd reads a byte it would notify through a channel. 100% reliable, and moves the fd  to Go's channels domain.

Comment: @chmike, you're over-thinking this. If you close the file in the same process you set the Go handle to a closed state and issue a close syscall. If you're blocked in the read, the OS will notify you via an error. If you're not in the read, Go will notify you when you try to read from a closed file handle. I wasn't able to confirm that, so at worst case if that's not thread-safe, you would need to maintain an atomic flag or similar for "closed" and check it before initiating a read from the file.

Answer (score 1):

All net.Conn's in Go can be accessed concurrently. If your library is based on that, there shouldn't be any problems.

Otherwise, it's quite common in Go to spawn one goroutine per connection. This goroutine often is just responsible for reading from the socket (which might block) and forward all the data to another coordinator goroutine using a channel. This coordinator goroutine is then able to interact with all those socket connections (which are wrapped in a channel) and other events using a select statement. Also note, that you can easily add a buffer to those channels, so that a slow client can't block your coordinator goroutine.

Comment: The library is not based on net.Conn's.  It specifically says that the socket can not be used from multiple threads concurrently: http://api.zeromq.org/2-2:zmq-socket.  I can't block trying to read on the socket, because I may need to write to the socket before any data has been received.